# What are Machine learning model characteristics?

Tags: machine-learning, modeling

This question I have received in some Machine Learning related interview and Here is the question

> *What questions would you ask to learn about machine learning model characteristics?*

***This is what I think:***

I did a bit research on the internet & found [this resource](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2012/02/characteristics-of-machine-learning.html), but still not very clear about How ML model characteristics are equivalent to asking trade-off between different algorithms in supervised learning settings. What I understood and framed my answer is:

1. First, for simplicity, I assumed that this model is used for some supervised learning task(classification/ regression) then,

   1. I would first try to find a learning algorithm used to create this model, because this will provide me with a clue of the created model and help me to talk about different issues within it(such as,

      - How complex or simple your model is(feature engineering!)?
      - What are your training & test errors(Model performance)

   Both will help me to talk about the bias vs variance trade-off.
2. Furthermore, I could talk about different learning algorithm trade-offs in supervised settings.

   - Is the model based on identifying correlations i.e output variable can be expressed in terms of the linear/non-linear combination of features?
     (targeting linear regression, logistic regression, SVM or Neural network algorithms, or
   - it's decision tree-based algorithms.

I am not confident enough that my answer is complete or correct (since I am not able to understand what precisely characteristics of a model are?), so I need this community's help to provide feedback! please feel free to add your suggestion to it!

Comment: It's hard to follow your post and understand what you are asking. It seems that you have a question about a question $Q$ and the answer $A$ that you provided to $Q$. Can you more clearly write your post so that both $Q$ and $A$ are clearly stated? One way to check if your writing is clear is to ask a friend *who is not a machine learning or statistics specialist* to read the post; if they understand the gist and can explain the post *to you*, then the post is probably clear enough.

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks for your suggestion, I have re-written it!. I provided answer `A` to the question `Q` and asked for community support to provide a suggestion if it is incorrect or incomplete. I hope it is clear this time. :)